# Slice lines and save parameters into different files

Tags: python, parsing, io, slice, text-extraction

I have a `g.out` file (pasted below).

This file consists of several `FINAL OPTIMIZED` geometries I would like to extract.

For a given `FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY`, these highlighted values are the ones I would like to extract:

[image]

I have managed in the below program to extract the first three: `VOLUME` and `A`, and `B`:

My code:

```
import os
import sys
import re

initial_pattern = '^ FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3$'
middle_pattern = '^ CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL '
end_pattern = '^ T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT$'


VOLUMES = []
P0 = []
P2 = []
atomic_number = []
coord_x = []
coord_y = []
coord_z = []

with open('g.out') as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match(initial_pattern, line):
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

            volume_line = file.next()
            print volume_line
            aux = volume_line.split()
            each_volume = aux[7]
            print each_volume
            VOLUMES.append(each_volume)

        if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
            print line

            print file.next()
            parameters_line = file.next()
            aux = parameters_line.split()
            p0 = aux[0]
            p1 = aux[1]
            p2 = aux[2]
            p3 = aux[3]
            p4 = aux[4]
            p5 = aux[5] # 

            print p0
            print p2

            P0.append(p0)
            P2.append(p2)

            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

            first_coord_line = file.next()
            print first_coord_line

        if re.match(end_pattern, line):
            end_pattern = line
            print end_pattern
            all_coordinates =  [first_coord_line:end_pattern]
            for line in all_coordinates:
              del('F ')             # delete those that contain 'F '
              aux2 =  line.split()
              coords = []


sys.exit()
#Template = 
"""
some stuff
other stuff
p0      p2
3
A    B        C         D
E    F        G         H
I    J        K         L
other stuff
some other stuff
"""
```

I am not able to extract the `COORDINATES`, because I cannot find the way to slice lines from `first_coord_line` to `end_pattern`, like in this pseudo-code:

```
if re.match(end_pattern, line):
    end_pattern = line
    print end_pattern
    all_coordinates =  [first_coord_line:end_pattern]
    for line in all_coordinates:
      del('F ')             # delete those that contain 'F '
      aux2 =  line.split()  # split lines
      atomic_number = aux2[2]
      coord_x = aux2[4]
      coord_y = aux2[5]
      coord_z = aux2[6]
```

Is there a way to achieve this pseudo-code?

In my code, `VOLUMES`, `P0`, `P2`, `atomic_number`, `coord_x`, `coord_y` `coord_z` are initialized with lists because before ending the for loop I would like to save in different files, named with the name of the "`VOLUME`.inp", this information:

```
#Template = 
"""
some stuff
other stuff
p0      p2
3
A    B        C         D
E    F        G         H
I    J        K         L
other stuff
some other stuff
"""
```

where `p0` and `p2` are the values extracted in my code (2nd and 3rd highlighted values  in the screenshot), and `A`-`L` are the `atomic_number` and  `coord_x`, `coord_y`, `coord_z`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

The `g.out` file:

```
more lines
more lines
more lines

 FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3
 (NON PERIODIC DIRECTION: LATTICE PARAMETER FORMALLY SET TO 500)
 *******************************************************************************
 LATTICE PARAMETERS (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - BOHR = 0.5291772083 ANGSTROM
 PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE 7/0 VOLUME=   119.823364 - DENSITY  2.770 g/cm^3
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     6.28373604     6.28373604     6.28373604    46.646397  46.646397  46.646397
 *******************************************************************************
 ATOMS IN THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT    3 - ATOMS IN THE UNIT CELL:   10
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01
      4 F   6 C    -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01
      5 T   8 O    -4.924094276183E-01 -7.590572381674E-03  2.500000000000E-01
      6 F   8 O     2.500000000000E-01 -4.924094276183E-01 -7.590572381674E-03
      7 F   8 O    -7.590572381674E-03  2.500000000000E-01 -4.924094276183E-01
      8 F   8 O     4.924094276183E-01  7.590572381674E-03 -2.500000000000E-01
      9 F   8 O    -2.500000000000E-01  4.924094276183E-01  7.590572381674E-03
     10 F   8 O     7.590572381674E-03 -2.500000000000E-01  4.924094276183E-01

 TRANSFORMATION MATRIX PRIMITIVE-CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
  1.0000  0.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000

 *******************************************************************************
 CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (VOLUME=        359.47009054)
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     4.97568007     4.97568007    16.76591397    90.000000  90.000000 120.000000

 COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.491739570355E-17 -2.745869785177E-17 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     3.333333333333E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      4 F   6 C    -3.333333333333E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      5 T   8 O    -4.090760942850E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      6 F   8 O     3.333333333333E-01 -7.574276095166E-02 -8.333333333333E-02
      7 F   8 O     7.574276095166E-02  4.090760942850E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      8 F   8 O     4.090760942850E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      9 F   8 O    -3.333333333333E-01  7.574276095166E-02  8.333333333333E-02
     10 F   8 O    -7.574276095166E-02 -4.090760942850E-01  8.333333333333E-02

 T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT
 INFORMATION **** fort.34 **** GEOMETRY OUTPUT FILE

more lines
more lines
more lines

 FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3
 (NON PERIODIC DIRECTION: LATTICE PARAMETER FORMALLY SET TO 500)
 *******************************************************************************
 LATTICE PARAMETERS (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - BOHR = 0.5291772083 ANGSTROM
 PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE 7/0 VOLUME=   121.143469 - DENSITY  2.740 g/cm^3
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     6.32229536     6.32229536     6.32229536    46.436583  46.436583  46.436583
 *******************************************************************************
 ATOMS IN THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT    3 - ATOMS IN THE UNIT CELL:   10
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA    5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01  2.500000000000E-01
      4 F   6 C    -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01 -2.500000000000E-01
      5 T   8 O    -4.927088991116E-01 -7.291100888437E-03  2.500000000000E-01
      6 F   8 O     2.500000000000E-01 -4.927088991116E-01 -7.291100888437E-03
      7 F   8 O    -7.291100888437E-03  2.500000000000E-01 -4.927088991116E-01
      8 F   8 O     4.927088991116E-01  7.291100888437E-03 -2.500000000000E-01
      9 F   8 O    -2.500000000000E-01  4.927088991116E-01  7.291100888437E-03
     10 F   8 O     7.291100888437E-03 -2.500000000000E-01  4.927088991116E-01

 TRANSFORMATION MATRIX PRIMITIVE-CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
  1.0000  0.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000

 *******************************************************************************
 CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL (VOLUME=        363.43040599)
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA
     4.98494429     4.98494429    16.88768068    90.000000  90.000000 120.000000

 COORDINATES IN THE CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL
     ATOM                 X/A                 Y/B                 Z/C
 *******************************************************************************
      1 T  20 CA    0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00  0.000000000000E+00
      2 F  20 CA   -5.471726358381E-17 -2.735863179191E-17 -5.000000000000E-01
      3 T   6 C     3.333333333333E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      4 F   6 C    -3.333333333333E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      5 T   8 O    -4.093755657782E-01 -3.333333333333E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      6 F   8 O     3.333333333333E-01 -7.604223244490E-02 -8.333333333333E-02
      7 F   8 O     7.604223244490E-02  4.093755657782E-01 -8.333333333333E-02
      8 F   8 O     4.093755657782E-01  3.333333333333E-01  8.333333333333E-02
      9 F   8 O    -3.333333333333E-01  7.604223244490E-02  8.333333333333E-02
     10 F   8 O    -7.604223244490E-02 -4.093755657782E-01  8.333333333333E-02

 T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT
 INFORMATION **** fort.34 **** GEOMETRY OUTPUT FILE

more lines
more lines
more lines
```

**Updated code:**

Based on @nos flag's approach, the following code is capable of extracting the information. `VOLUMES` is a list of 2 elements. 
The following lists are the result:

```
VOLUMES =  ['119.823364', '121.143469']
P0 =  ['4.97568007', '4.98494429']
P2 =  ['16.76591397', '16.88768068']
Xs =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.090760942850E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '3.333333333333E-01', '-4.093755657782E-01']
Ys =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01', '0.000000000000E+00', '-3.333333333333E-01', '-3.333333333333E-01']
Zs =  ['0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02', '0.000000000000E+00', '-8.333333333333E-02', '-8.333333333333E-02']
ATOMIC_NUMBERS =  ['20', '6', '8', '20', '6', '8']
```

The second part of this post was to write this information (`P0`, `P2`, `ATOMIC_NUMBERS`, `Xs`, `Ys`, `Zs`) in the two `VOLUME.inp` files. In other words, something like:

`V_119.823364.inp` file:

```
some stuff
other stuff
4.97568007   4.98494429
3
20 0.000000000000E+00    0.000000000000E+00   0.000000000000E+00
6  3.333333333333E-01   -3.333333333333E-01  -8.333333333333E-02
8 -4.090760942850E-01   -3.333333333333E-01  -8.333333333333E-02
other stuff
```

`V_121.143469.inp` file:

```
some stuff
other stuff
4.97568007   4.98494429
3
20 0.000000000000E+00    0.000000000000E+00   0.000000000000E+00
6  3.333333333333E-01   -3.333333333333E-01  -8.333333333333E-02
8 -4.093755657782E-01   -3.333333333333E-01  -8.333333333333E-02
other stuff
```

Based on @nos's `atoms_per_frame` and `atoms_all_frames` suggestion, I have tried the following code. I am finding difficulties in writing element-wise to the files, i.e.:

```
import os
import sys
import re
import glob

initial_pattern = '^ FINAL OPTIMIZED GEOMETRY - DIMENSIONALITY OF THE SYSTEM      3$'
middle_pattern = '^ CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC CELL '
end_pattern = '^ T = ATOM BELONGING TO THE ASYMMETRIC UNIT$'

global N_atom_irreducible_unit
N_atom_irreducible_unit = 3

VOLUMES = []
P0 = []
P2 = []
ATOMIC_NUMBERS = []
Xs = []
Ys = []
Zs = []

with open('g.out') as file:
    passed_mid_point = False
    for line in file:
        if re.match(initial_pattern, line):
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

            volume_line = file.next()
            print volume_line
            aux = volume_line.split()
            each_volume = aux[7]
            print each_volume
            VOLUMES.append(each_volume)

        if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
            print line

            print file.next()
            parameters_line = file.next()
            aux = parameters_line.split()
            p0 = aux[0]
            p1 = aux[1]
            p2 = aux[2]
            p3 = aux[3]
            p4 = aux[4]
            p5 = aux[5] # 

            print p0
            print p2

            P0.append(p0)
            P2.append(p2)

            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()
            print file.next()

        if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = True
            print 'line = ', line

        if re.match(end_pattern, line):
            passed_mid_point = False

        elif passed_mid_point:
            # parse the coordinates
            print 'line2 =', line
            terms = line.split()
            print 'terms =', terms

        if terms and terms[1] == 'T':
            print terms[1]
            atomic_number = terms[2]
            print 'atomic_number = ', atomic_number
            ATOMIC_NUMBERS.append(atomic_number)

            x = terms[4]
            print 'x =', x
            Xs.append(x)

            y = terms[5]
            print 'y = ', y
            Ys.append(y)

            z = terms[6]
            print 'z = ', z
            Zs.append(z)

print 'VOLUMES = ', VOLUMES
print 'P0 = ', P0
print 'P2 = ', P2
print 'Xs = ', Xs
print 'Ys = ', Ys
print 'Zs = ', Zs
print 'ATOMIC_NUMBERS = ', ATOMIC_NUMBERS

# create the empty list of lists:
atoms_all_frames = [[] for _ in xrange(len(VOLUMES))]
print atoms_all_frames

for index_vol in range(len(VOLUMES)):
  for index in range(len(ATOMIC_NUMBERS)):
    atoms_per_frame = [ATOMIC_NUMBERS[index], Xs[index], Ys[index], Zs[index]]
    atoms_all_frames[index_vol].append(atoms_per_frame)

# "atoms_all_frames" would be an appropriate list for looping
print atoms_all_frames

# Remove any existing V*.inp files, to clean first: 
for f in glob.glob("V*.inp"):
  os.remove(f)

# create the files:
for V in VOLUMES:
  filename = "V_{}.d12".format(V)
  print filename

  # open them:
  with open(filename,"a") as f:

   # the following is a pseudo-code, because I cannot manage to 
   # find the way to write element-wise each string to the files:
   for p0, p2, atoms_all_frames:

      f.write("""some stuff
other stuff
%s      %s
%s
%s    %s        %s         %s
%s    %s        %s         %s
%s    %s        %s         %s
other stuff
some other stuff\n""" % p0 % p2 %N_atom_irreducible_unit %atoms_all_frames)
```

Comment: Too much code and text...

Comment: I'm guessing you are parsing some results per (time) frame, and for each frame there is volume, and potentially multiple atoms with their coordinates. In that case, first create a list (say `atoms_all_frames = []`) to hold all atom results. Then as you parse the file, create a list of atom coordinates (say `atoms_per_frame = []`) for each frame, and append the (x, y, z) coordinates for each atom into it. Then append `atoms_per_frame` into `atoms_all_frames`. This way, your volume list and coordinate list would have the same size, which is the number of frame.

Comment: @nos Thanks for your suggestion. I have followed that approach, but I cannot manage to write element-wise to the files. Please see updated post

Comment: It's not clear to me where you get stuck. Can you confirm that your `atoms_per_frame` is already what you expected?

Comment: @nos I understand there is a lot of information here and you might find it confusing. Thus, I have created another post with this second part of the post. The first part of the post was solved, so I accept this answer. Please,  look in:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061013/writing-simultaneously-into-several-files-the-elements-of-lists-of-different-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The essential thing is to distinguish whether you have passed the `mid_pattern` since the same coordinate pattern exists both before and after it, and only the ones after it is desired.

For example, you can

1. set a flag so we know `mid_pattern` has matched
2. branch out at the `end_pattern` matching

   ```
   passed_mid_point = False
   ...
   if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
       passed_mid_point = True
       # do what you need
       ...
   if re.match(end_pattern, line):
       passed_mid_point = False # so you can process a new frame
       # do what you need after end pattern is matched
       ...
   elif passed_mid_point:
       # parse the coordinates
       terms = line.split()
       if terms and terms[1] == 'T':
           x = float(terms[4])
           y = float(terms[5])
           z = float(terms[6])
   ```

Or, you can flag and match, something like this:

```
    passed_mid_point = False
    coord_patter = r'      \d+ T '
    ...
    if re.match(middle_pattern, line):
        passed_mid_point = True
        # do what you need
        ...
    if re.match(end_pattern, line):
        passed_mid_point = False # so you can process a new frame
        # do what you need after end pattern is matched
        ...
    if passed_mid_point and re.match(coord_pattern, line):
        # parse the coordinates
        terms = line.split()
        if terms and terms[1] == 'T':
            x = float(terms[4])
            y = float(terms[5])
            z = float(terms[6])
```

The coordinate matching can be done fully in regular expression as well

```
sci_num = r'-?\d+\.\d*E[+\-]\d+'
coord_pattern = r'\s+\d+\sT\s+\d+\s+[A-Z]+\s+(%s)\s+(%s)\s+(%s)' % (sci_num, sci_num, sci_num)
coord_re = re.compile(coord_pattern)
if coord_re.match(line):
    x = float(coord_re.group(1))
    y = float(coord_re.group(2))
    z = float(coord_re.group(3))
```

For recording the data, it will be better if you keep track of the frame that the atom coordinates belong to. For example, you can create a `atom_frames` at the beginning. And keep appending list of atom coordinates to it where each list corresponds to a frame. Overall it looks something like this

```
atom_frames = []
for i in range(50): # here I assume 50 frames
    current_frame = []
    for a in atoms_in_this_frame:
        current_frame.append(a)  # a could be (x, y, z) of an atom
    atom_frames.append(current_frame)
```

Here I just loop over the frame counts. In your case, you can create `current_frame = []` when you hit the `mid_pattern`. And do `atom_frames.append(current_frame)` when you hit `end_pattern`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This flag procedure approach is very interesting. I have applied this principle in the code. However, when reaching the `if terms[1] == 'T':` statement, there is a `list index out of range` error. See **updated code**  to reproduce the problem. The `if terms[1] == 'T':` statement seems fine to me, I quite do not understand where is the problem

Comment: oh, this is because there are blank lines, see the updated code

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and thanks again for all your help. The part that saves the information to files presents some difficulties. See **updated code**.